# Trying to select tables based on user input but it won't work

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I'm new to crystal reports I'm trying to change the selected tables based on user input in SAP crystal reports but when I enter a value it shows an error message, this is the code :

````
if({?Type}='Commande client') begin select rdr1.docentry,rdr1.itemCode, rdr1.dscription, rdr1.quantity,rdr1.price,rdr1.currency,rdr1.slpCode,rdr1.basedocnum,
rdr1.shiptocode,rdr1.shiptodesc,rdr1.baseprice,rdr1.itemtype,ordr.docnum,ordr.doctype,ordr.docstatus,ordr.docTotal,ordr.docdate,
ordr.cardcode,ordr.cardname,ordr.address,ordr.doccur,ordr.paidtodate,ordr.doctime,ordr.docsubtype,ordr.basetype,
ordr.baseEntry from ordr inner join rdr1 on ordr.docentry=rdr1.docentry end

if({?Type}='Offre/Devis client') begin select qut1.docentry,qut1.itemCode, qut1.dscription, qut1.quantity,qut1.price,qut1.currency,
qut1.slpCode,qut1.basedocnum,qut1.shiptocode,qut1.shiptodesc,qut1.baseprice,qut1.itemtype,oqut.docnum,oqut.doctype,oqut.docstatus,
oqut.docTotal,oqut.docdate,oqut.cardcode,oqut.cardname,oqut.address,oqut.doccur,oqut.paidtodate,oqut.doctime,oqut.docsubtype,
oqut.basetype, oqut.baseEntry from oqut inner join qut1 on oqut.docentry=qut1.docentry end

if({?Type}='Livraison client') begin select dln1.docentry,dln1.itemCode, dln1.dscription, dln1.quantity,dln1.price,dln1.currency,
dln1.slpCode,dln1.basedocnum,dln1.shiptocode,dln1.shiptodesc,dln1.baseprice,dln1.itemtype,odln.docnum,odln.doctype,odln.docstatus,
odln.docTotal,odln.docdate,odln.cardcode,odln.cardname,odln.address,odln.doccur,odln.paidtodate,odln.doctime,odln.docsubtype,
odln.basetype, odln.baseEntry from odln inner join dln1 on odln.docentry=dln1.docentry end
```[text is in French but it basically translates to: impossible to extract data from data base
Native error: 102 [supplier code of the database: 102 ][1]
could anyone tell where the problem is.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pro8O.png
````

Comment: Error messages include vital information that tells you what's wrong. Please include it in your question

Comment: Formatting your SQL Queries, or any written media for that matter, is a must for readable text too.

Comment: Your error is "Incorrect syntax near 'Client'". I don't know crystal-reports, but it looks like `{?Type}` needs quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix it, it just needed quotes:

declare @type nvarchar(30)

set @type= '{?Type}'